# Error while adding SCALA IDE with eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I get the Following Error while installing plugin of SCALA IDE. The same happened for Eclipse Juno and Eclipse Juno(ADT)

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Scala IDE for Eclipse dev support 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503032103-b2bbad6 (org.scala-ide.sdt.dev.feature.feature.group 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503032103-b2bbad6)
  Missing requirement: Scala Plugin 4.0.0.v-2_11-201412171518-2279837 (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4.0.0.v-2_11-201412171518-2279837) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.9.0,3.10.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Scala Plugin 4.0.0.v-2_11-201501131019-027320c (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4.0.0.v-2_11-201501131019-027320c) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.9.0,3.10.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Scala Plugin 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503032103-b2bbad6 (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503032103-b2bbad6) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 1.0.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Scala IDE for Eclipse dev support 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503032103-b2bbad6 (org.scala-ide.sdt.dev.feature.feature.group 4.0.0.v-2_11-201503032103-b2bbad6)
    To: org.scala-ide.sdt.core 0.0.0
```

Please help regarding this.I have searched several posts regarding the dependency error But was unable to find solution.

Comment: do you have jdt core component installed in your eclipse in required version?

Comment: Looks like it requires Eclipse Kepler

Comment: How to add jdt core with the required version?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I updated my version of eclipse juno to eclipse luna. Then I added the plugin. And  It worked Great.
The update can be done using:-
The Eclipse Project Updates - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4